# Smarty - load multiple sections from config file

Tags: variables, configuration, smarty, smarty3

I'm new to Smarty and now playing with it and see what it can do. I stumble upon this situation, and did not find any reference in documentation:
If I have multiple sections in test.conf file,

```
sitename = "Testing Smarty"
[basic]
apply = true
denied = false
[images]
width = 60px
height = 80px
[anythingelse]
foo = "Yes"
bar = "No"
```

how can I include all of these sections at once?

If I put:

```
{config_load file="test.conf"}
```

Smarty will return only variables, which are not in any sections. Therefore {$smarty.config.sitename} or #sitename# will work, but any other variable will not be loaded.

If I put:

```
{config_load file="test.conf" section="basic"}
```

Smarty will return variables, which are not in any sections and adds all variables in "basic" section.

Is it possible to add all sections at once? Or do I have to call

```
{config_load file="test.conf" section="some_section"}
```

for every section I have in configuration file?

Comment: If you want to include everything anyway, why use sections?

Comment: @Borgtex Well, what if I create another file, from which I want to load data from 4 sections? Or let's say that i want to have 1 config file and multiple templates, which loads more than 1 section into a site. How can I specify from which sections load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation it's not possible. There's no info you can load multiple config sections. However if you could load config files not in template itself but in PHP as in documentation, http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.config.load.tpl , you can create array of sections and then in loop load sections you want, so you should achieve what you want:

```
$sections = array('section1', 'section2', 'section10');

foreach ($sections as $section) {
    $smarty->configLoad('filename.conf', $section);
```

}

It should work but I haven't tested it (never needed such functionality and at the moment don't have any smarty project to test)